# getting ORA-12545 even though host name is correct

Tags: oracle, database-connectivity

I am try to access remote database by making these changes to my tnsnames.ora file (sorry won't declare host names and service name here)

```
MYDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host_name)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xxxx.edu)
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\nsm\product\12.1.0\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

However,I am getting ORA-12545 and looks like hostname is not right.Actually,one other person connected to the db using the very same host name but I can't connect.Is there anything wrong with my ora file? I am using Windows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My tnsnames is a bit different. It has an ADDRESS_LIST containing the ADDRESS item. I don't think this will help, but just in case... You never know...

Comment: thanks! yes tried with ADDRESS_LIST too.Din't work :(

Comment: Syntax is fine. What does `tnsping mydb` say? Although tnsping is primitive, it only checks the host and port and bypasses everything else. Also, please post `sqlnet.ora` file details.

Comment: it gives TNS-03545 (failed to resolve name).

Comment: @user3400060 That would mean either your host or port is incorrect. Or, there is a firewall or connectivity issue to the host/port.

Comment: From command prompt what does `ping host` say? Also double check the tnsnames.ora content.

Comment: ping: cannot resolve host_name: Unknown host

Comment: turning on firewall did not help either

Comment: That concludes the issue is with the host. Either it is incorrect or not reachable. And I meant turning off the firewall not the other way round. Do you have access to remote server?

Comment: Is this database running on your local PC?

Comment: no...on remote server

Comment: I can ping this host when I connect to my school linux machine.Can't connect it using cmd or mac terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Windows 10 client, where both IPv6 and IPv4 were active. Apparently, it was trying to resolve the host name through IPv6 where the domain doesn't exist, instead of our IPv4 DNS.

Disabling IPv6 on the network adapter fixed the problem, until we can get the name resolution working on both 4 and 6.